# Problem with Phonegap eclipse plugin installation

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation, cordova

I followed this link to install Phonegap eclipse plugin for android 
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap%20Eclipse%20PlugIn%20for%20Android

but its showing the below  errors/messages. I tried several times but I couldnt understand the messages its showing.

What should I do to fix it? need your suggestions.

Thanks.

```
 Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: PhonegapForAndroid 1.2.4.201108181012 (com.mds.phonegapForAndroid.feature.group 1.2.4.201108181012)
 Software currently installed: Eclipse SDK 3.5.0.I20090611-1540 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.5.0.I20090611-1540)
      Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
     Core Resource Management 3.5.0.v20090512 (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.5.0.v20090512)
    Core Resource Management 3.5.2.R35x_v20091203-1235 (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.5.2.R35x_v20091203-1235)
     Core Resource Management 3.5.1.R35x_v20090826-0451 (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.5.1.R35x_v20090826-0451)
      Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Phonegap for Android 1.2.4.201108181012 (com.mds.apg 1.2.4.201108181012)
To: bundle org.eclipse.core.resources 3.5.2
    Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: PhonegapForAndroid 1.2.4.201108181012 (com.mds.phonegapForAndroid.feature.group 1.2.4.201108181012)
To: com.mds.apg [1.2.4.201108181012]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Platform 3.5.0.v20090611a-9gEeG1HFtQcmRThO4O3aR_fqSMvJR2sJ (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.5.0.v20090611a-9gEeG1HFtQcmRThO4O3aR_fqSMvJR2sJ)
    To: org.eclipse.core.resources [3.5.0.v20090512]
   Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Project SDK 3.5.0.v20090423-7Q7bA7DPQ1SM6OYQ7wKYJhI-z-xZJCmLTBRhtZ0o61b1z (org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group 3.5.0.v20090423-7Q7bA7DPQ1SM6OYQ7wKYJhI-z-xZJCmLTBRhtZ0o61b1z)
  To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.5.0.v20090611a-9gEeG1HFtQcmRThO4O3aR_fqSMvJR2sJ]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
     From: Eclipse SDK 3.5.0.I20090611-1540 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.5.0.I20090611-1540)
   To: org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group [3.5.0.v20090423-7Q7bA7DPQ1SM6OYQ7wKYJhI-z-xZJCmLTBRhtZ0o61b1z]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need to install phonegap  in eclipse.you need add phonegap.jar to your project and few changes....read it and ... http://www.phonegap.com/start#android

Answer (score 2):

The AppLaud Eclipse plugin for PhoneGap requires at minimum of Eclipse 3.6 (Helios).  It does not work with 3.5 (Galileo).  The plugin also works with 3.7 (Indigo).

It's true that you can work around not having the plugin, but it makes PhoneGap project start-up much easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply,could u suggest which way is best? adding phonegap.jar or as you said, coz I want to devolep the projects for a company not for just practice. I mean for long time basis which one is best?

Comment: I think using the AppLaud plugin is best since it's wizard does all of the project configuration for you. You don't need to worry about the right place for phonegap.jar and other files. (Note, I'm the author of the plugin, so might be a little biased :-)